# Edit and update HTML datatable Django

Tags: jquery, html, django, django-templates, models

I just builded a system in Django 1.10 that basically is a form that **users can fill up and generates technical issues from orders.** As seen in the picture below:

[image]

**Once the issue is submitted to the database below is a table where all the issues appear:**
[image]

This is my model:

```
class TechnicalValidationSystem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    soss = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    case_opened = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cause_reason = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    issue_solved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is my HTML table:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>SO-SS</th>
                                        <th>Case Opened</th>
                                        <th>Cause Reason</th>
                                        <th>Comments</th>
                                        <th>Date Created</th>
                                        <th>Created by:</th>
                                        <th>Issue Solved?</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {% for linea in lineas_de_reporte %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ linea.soss }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ linea.case_opened }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ linea.cause_reason }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ linea.comments }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ linea.date_created }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ linea.author }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ linea.issue_solved }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>

                            </table>
                        </div>
```

**What I need now is to find a way users can modify this table mainly if the issue was solved or not and to update my database with that response. Anyone know how to do this with just django? if not maybe use Jquery or anything else.**

Let me know if you guys need something else or if I miss something, thanks you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE]: Something like that in your HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="..." >
        <thead>
            ...
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for linea in lineas_de_reporte %}
                <tr>
                    ...
                    <td>
                        <form action="{% url 'view_name' %}" method="GET">
                            <input type="hidden" name="linea-id" value="{{ linea.id }}" />
                            <input type="submit" name="submit-issue-solved" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Yes, this can happen with Django only (and with jQuery if you like).

You should alter the `ISSUE RESOLVED?` column to a form where each cell (using the [`{% for %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for) loop, of course) will contain two radio buttons (`Yes` and `No`), a hidden one (with the value of a unique key. I guess `SOSS` is unique accross your db table?) and a submit button next to the radio ones.

Then, that form should submit itself (determined via the `action={% url 'a_view_name_here' %}` attribute) to a `url` and handled by a `view`. Inside that view you can get the value, user selected (depending on the method used, i.e `request.GET.get('issue_resolved')` or `request.POST.get('issue_resolved')`) and in the same way the value of the unique value (i.e `SOSS`).

Finally, you'll make a query to the db to get the `TechnicalValidationSystem` with that `SOSS` and update its `issue_resolved` boolean value (like this:

```
def issue_resolved(request):
    # if GET data contain a key named 'linea-id'...
    if request.GET.get('linea-id'):
        # ... this means that user clicked on the submit button
        # get the id of linea
        linea_id = request.GET.get('linea-id')
        # fetch object from db, based on that id (aka pk)
        linea = TechnicalValidationSystem.objects.get(id=linea_id)
        # change its attribute to True
        linea.issue_resolved = True
        # update db with the new value
        linea.save(update_fields=['issue_resolved'])
    return render(request, 'template/to/the/table.html', context_here)
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, my SOSS is not my unique key I set the ID as default to keep track of the cases. How do I alter column to a form? this means instead of calling linea.issue_solved y need to configure a radio button there? how do I do that? sorry I´m new into this :(

Comment: Show me your HTML file where you present the table

Comment: is below my model in my question, or you need more?

Comment: Which ID? The primary key? You should define at least one unique field amongst your model fields. You must choose one that's going to be unique!

Comment: Yeah when you don´t assign a primary key it creates an id by default as the primary. So you suggest to set SOSS as  the primary?

Comment: or what I can do it add the ID to my html <td>{{ linea.id }}</td>

Comment: If `SOSS` is going to be unique across all current and future records, then yes. If no, choose an other one that fulfills the above requirement.

Comment: Yes, OK. You can do it like that. Here's comes my updated answer!

Comment: Yeah I can't set my SOSS as primary because users may create more that one case using the same SOSS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137789/discussion-between-deluq-and-nik-m).